# jquery show hide tr by select option

Tags: jquery, select

My goal is to show / hide tr by a select.

I have a `<select>` with `id="selcat"` and a table with `id="maplist"`. The select control's `<options>` are generated from a MySQL recordset and displays all by default.

(in the source code my val options are what they seems to be)

Now I want to filter this without a page refresh via jQuery.

I've tried this:

```
$('select#selcat').change(function() {
    $("#maplist tr").hide().filter($(this).val()).show();
}).change();
});
```

But all tr's are being hidden with this code and I was wondering what's wrong.

Comment: Do the rows have ID's or classes? How are you matching your select values to rows?

Comment: Did you try using the `option` value without show/hide to see if the query and filter are returning the unhidden tr's?  Also, you want to use a callback or `.then()` to delay the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following HTML:

```
<select id="selcat">
    <option value="[data-val='a']">A</option>
    <option value="[data-val='b']">B</option>
    <option value="[data-val='c']">C</option>
</select>

<table id="maplist">
    <tr data-val="a"><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="a"><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="b"><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="b"><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr data-val="c"><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then your jquery should work:

```
$('select#selcat').change(function() {
    $("#maplist tr").hide().filter($(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

My guess is that you are sending an incorrect filter value in your code, which is why people wanted to see your HTML.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jwsj/

Comment: ok, here's some more explanation.
the html of my my table looks like
<table id="maplist">
<tr><td>some school</td><td><input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="school" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>some hotel</td><td><input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="hotel" /></td></tr></table>

my select looks like this
<select name="selcat" id="selcat">
<option value="school">school</option>
<option value="hotel">hotel</option>
</select> 
ik like to filter the table rows by the select where the options value = the value of the hiddenfield